# Sql query with join to return a part number that exists in one table and does not exist in another table with other field data

Tags: sql-server-2005, left-join, not-exists

I'm trying to return data from one table A that does not exist in table B with certain data.  For instance:

```
Table A     No_         Inventory Posting Group
             1           PAR
             2           NEW
             3           PAR
             4           PAR

Table B     No_         Table ID       Dimension Code
             1           27             Branch
             2           27             Manufacturer
             3           27             Department
             3           27             Branch
             5           27             Department
```

Every part No_ exists in table A.  Table B needs to have both "Branch" and "Department" on a separate row.  Some parts have one or the other or both in Table B.  I'm trying to return results that show for every part listed in table A which ones are not present for "Branch" and "Department" in table B.  It may be two separate queries.   Here is what I have now, but I'm not getting what I want.

```
select dd.[No_], dd.[Table ID], dd.[Dimension Code], dd.[Dimension Value Code], dd.[Value Posting], dd.[Multi Selection Action]
from [Item] i left outer join [Default Dimension] dd

on  i.[No_] = dd.[No_]

where dd.[Dimension Code] not in ('BRANCH', 'DEPARTMENT')
and i.[Inventory Posting Group] = 'PAR'
and dd.[Table ID] = 27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT dd.[No_]
FROM [Item] i
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Default Dimension] dd ON  i.[No_] = dd.[No_]
WHERE i.[Inventory Posting Group] = 'PAR'
  AND dd.[No_] IS NULL
```

The idea is that when you left join a table, the missing matching records from the right table will have `NULL` values.

**EDIT** To get the records that don't have a particular `Dimension Code`, you will need to join a table that has the list of dimensions. If you don't have such a table, you can create a fake one in a sub query:

```
SELECT i.[No_], d.Dimension AS Missing_Dimension
FROM [Item] i
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'DEPARTMENT' AS Dimension
            UNION
            SELECT 'BRANCH' AS Dimension) AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Default Dimension] dd ON i.[No_] = dd.[No_]
            AND dd.[Dimension Code] = d.Dimension
WHERE i.[Inventory Posting Group] = 'PAR'
  AND dd.[No_] IS NULL
ORDER BY i.[No_]
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63889/30).

Comment: That gives me the part numbers that don't have either BRANCH or DEPARTMENT  in table B but does not give me which ones have only one or the other or both.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. You asked **I'm trying to return results that show for every part listed in table A which ones are not present for "Branch" and "Department" in table B**, and that's what I answered. I don't really understand your comment. What do you exactly want?

Comment: If a part No_ in Table A is not listed in table B with "DEPARTMENT" as it's "Dimension Code" then I want to know that part No_ so I can add it into table B. Same thing for "BRANCH".  Again, probably two separate queries.

Comment: This returns 0 results.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. See my updated answer. I added a fiddle for you at the end so you can see the results.

Comment: This was awesome.  Perfect.  Didn't mean for you to write it for me but thanks...very much.